# What's the entry point/control flow in a Cocoa app with a GUI?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, events, user-interface

In console applications there generally is a main file where you type up what you want your program to do. In event-driven GUI programs, you have event handlers for each function (such as in Visual C# Windows Forms).

In Cocoa GUI applications, I don't see a centralized place where I can make variables and run commands. For example, I can make a new class and define all its member functions and data, but I don't have a place to actually make a new object of that class. Where do I put my "actual program"? I cannot find a file where all parts of the program are put together, I only seem to be able to define classes. A main file and function exists, but they aren't supposed to be used -- `main()` just starts up the application.

How does this work? Where do I put my program's code?

Comment: http://gnustep.made-it.com/BG-objc/#AEN73

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I am talking about using Objective C in Cocoa not in console applications.

Comment: @Farhead That has nothing to do with the entrypoint?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cocoa is an event driven environment, in many ways like .NET. In the vast majority of cases, the system will call you rather than you calling it. So like in your experience with C#, you're going to hook into various places and wait until you're called.

There are two main places you're going to put your startup "things." First is the Storyboard or main nib file (Storyboards are new in iOS 5). Any objects you create in your main nib file (or Storyboard) will be automatically created when the program starts. They can then respond to methods like `awakeFromNib` and `viewDidLoad`.

The other major place to kick things off is in the application delegate. This is not the home for all your program, but it is generally the first piece of "your" code that gets run. In particular, you want to add startup code to `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:`.

Before you go any further, I recommend you spend some time in the [iOS Starting Point](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_iPhoneGeneral/_index.html) document. If you want to skip ahead a little, you can go to the [iOS App Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html). (I assume you're asking about iOS because most people do these days. If you want Mac, it is very similar. Start with [Your First Mac App](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html).)

Apple documentations tends to be extremely good once you have a feel for where things are. And Cocoa is incredibly consistent (again, once you have a sense of what it's going to be consistent *with*). Make sure to read the documents labeled "Programming Guides" rather than just the Reference docs. And when you read the Reference docs, make sure to read the paragraphs at the top. If you just jump into all the method explanations, you'll skip most of the useful information.

Comment: Thank You. That answered everything except for one thing. Would I put calls to member functions in the application delegate? If not, where would I put calls to member functions?

Comment: That would strongly depend on which kind of methods you're referring to (ObjC never calls them "member functions"). The key point is that there is an event loop that you do not control. It will call your delegate methods when various events happen. So it would be common to call the method `init` on one of your objects from the application delegate. But most of the time you're going to be getting called by by system (again, just like in .NET).

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you have a main.m file in your project.

The default one generated by Xcode for an iOS App:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([MPAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say I am talking about using Objective C with Cocoa, not in console applications.

Comment: Whether its a GUI app or a console app, the very first entry point is indeed in main().